# MYSQL SELECT data without specified values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select some data from a table with a list of excluded fields.

```
public function get_columns($table, $excluded_columns = 'id, deleted')
{
    $this->db->select('column_name');
    $this->db->from("information_schema.COLUMNS");
    $this->db->where('TABLE_SCHEMA', $this->db->database);
    $this->db->where('TABLE_NAME', $table);
    $this->db->where('COLUMN_KEY !=', 'MUL');
    $result = $this->db->get()->{$this->_return_type(1)}();
    $result = array_column($result, 'column_name');

    return $result;
}
```

In my example I want all column_name without id and deleted, so how can I select data without specified values?

Comment: `$this->db->where('column_name != ', 'id');` ?

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 columns one called `id` and another called `deleted` but you do not want those columns in the result?

Comment: Yes. I don't want them in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function for one table, you can make array of exists fields:

```
$fields = ['id', 'deleted', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzzz']
```

and give to functions excluded columns like array

```
$excluded_columns = ['id', 'deleted'].
```

To get fields to fetch use

```
$tmp_fields = array_diff[$fields, $excluded_fields]
```

in query select parse the `$tmp_fields`

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you that its proper way or not. but i can do it in core like:

```
/* Get the data into a temp table */
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM YourTable
/* Drop the cloumns that are not needed */
ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN ColumnToDrop
/* Get results and drop temp table */
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

So let me know your thougths

Comment: He does not want to drop these columns, he just wants to remove rows from his query result. Its just a query not a table maintenace issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly all you need to do is add the column names that you do not want to see a result for to you query like this

```
public function get_columns($table, $excluded_columns = 'id, deleted')
{
    $this->db->select('column_name');
    $this->db->from("information_schema.COLUMNS");
    $this->db->where('TABLE_SCHEMA', $this->db->database);
    $this->db->where('TABLE_NAME', $table);
    $this->db->where('COLUMN_KEY !=', 'MUL');

    // 2 new criteria added 
    $this->db->where('COLUMN_NAME !=', 'id');
    $this->db->where('COLUMN_NAME !=', 'deleted');

    $result = $this->db->get()->{$this->_return_type(1)}();
    $result = array_column($result, 'column_name');

    return $result;
}
```